# How to use the D3.JS library for data visualization?

Tags: charts

What are the available options for using the [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) library in Drupal for creating data visualizations?

D3.js (Data-Driven Documents) appears to be a charting engine with an ever growing popularity. So I wonder how to somehow use D3.JS as a charting engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least 3 contributed modules which may help to use the [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) library (open source, released under the [BSD license](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause)) in a Drupal 7 site:

- [Charts and Graphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts_graphs):

  > Charts and Graphs is an API for developers. It can be extended by third-party modules that want to add their own charting implementations. It does nothing by itself. It should only be installed if some other module requires it.
- [D3](https://www.drupal.org/project/d3) (Alfa release only):

  > creates visualizations as [libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) (alpha version only) which allows one to add/remove visualizations, share them between modules, and integrate them with (for example: [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)) through library .info files.

  The [Basic module configuration](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/14DYgWTBUE8F9Pko3AFJd3bLNO5wXBix_lkWERheMLAw/edit#slide=id.p) presentation provides a short intro about how to use the module in combination with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).
- [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena)

  - [Comment 7 in issue 2364427](https://www.drupal.org/node/2364427#comment-9363133) contains an example of a custom module to use the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module for creating charts using the d3.js library.
  - [Issue # 2383509](https://www.drupal.org/node/2383509) describes the approaches for using D3 with Forena.

If you decide to not use any of these modules, it may help to get started with D3.js integration in Drupal by just looking at the code of these modules. Either to roll your own D3.js cookies via a custom module, or at least to get an idea of the required effort.

The [D3.JS Tutorial](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) is a great place for documentation about how to use this library.

Comment: Thanks for the question and answer :) I didn't know D3 before.

Answer (score 2):

The Drupal 8 version of [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) (disclosure, I'm a co-maintainer) supports three libraries:

- [C3.js](http://c3js.org/) (new as of D8).
- Google Charts and Highcharts (both similar to what is already in D7, now also for D8).

Some more details about how **`C3.js`** relates to **`D3.js`**:

> **C3** is a D3-based reusable charting library, more details about it can be found at [c3js.org](http://c3js.org/).

The current (D8) version of [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) is already [available on Github](https://github.com/andileco/d8charts), which is about to be released on [Drupal.Org](https://www.drupal.org/) as the **Alfa1** version of [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) also, as part of the newly launched <kbd>D8Charts</kbd> initiative (which got launched on Mar 10, 2017).